# Solving a linear system of equations with sympy where the solution might be indeterminate

Tags: python, math, sympy, linear-algebra, equation

As per the title, I have the following matrix representing a linear system of equations:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x, y, z, k

s = Matrix((
    (1, -1, k ** 2 - k + 2, k),
    (1, -1, 2, 0),
    (1, k - 2, 3, 2),
))
```

By doing `linsolve(s)` we get
`FiniteSet((-1/(k**2 - 2*k + 1), (2*k - 3)/(k**2 - 2*k + 1), 1/(k - 1)))`.
By substituting `k = 0` into this, we get `FiniteSet((-1, -3, -1))`. If we instead do the substitution first, doing `linsolve(s.subs(k, 0), x, y, z)` we get the correct result of `FiniteSet((-z - 2, z - 2, z))`.

As you can see, in the case where a value of `k` would give a parametric solution, doing the substitution *after* the solve returns the wrong solution(s), while doing it *before* returns the right solution(s). How can I fix this? Am I just using sympy incorrectly or is there a way to get the parametric solution without knowing beforehand that `k = 0` is "problematic"?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I think it's worth discussing this in a GitHub issue rather than here: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: Generally speaking a function like `linsolve` will return a result that is "generically" true for "most" values of the symbolic parameters e.g. in this case for any value of `k` *except* `0` and `1`.

Comment: Absolutely. However, I think there should be an indication of "these values are problematic" even if it means I have to rerun linsolve. If there isn't, then I will create a github issue and see what the developers can say about it. :)